# Calling a .net function from C++

Tags: c++, .net, windows

I want to use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485721%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) function to zip up a folder from a C++ console application. No examples are given in the article of how to use the function from C++, just C# or VB, and I can't find any other code samples anywhere.

The article doesn't really even clarify whether the function is available in C++. Is this function supported in C++? And if so, how do I call it?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using native C++, or C++/CLI? If you're using the latter, then the documentation on the link you gave has an example for C++...

Comment: I'm using native C++.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your specific question of calling that .NET method you requested, but, if you want to compress some files using native C++, look at using [Zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and there is a contribution app called [minizip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html) which you can use for opening / creating zip archives.